# flutter has exited unexpectedly FileSystemException :Creation Failed path=directory\lib OS Error: The system cannot find the file specified, errno = 2

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I an tring to create a new flutter project with flutter3.3.0 but suddenly came below exception.
[image]
after run flutter doctor, [image]

[image]
not create any directory in project

[image]

also change variables

Comment: @MansoorMalik tried but not work

Comment: @MansoorMalik no issue found

Comment: @MansoorMalik yes

Comment: I also tried change flutter sdk but did not work, reinstalling flutter and android studio but did not work

Comment: Please share the flutter doctor -v command output here

Comment: @HardikMehta I need to run this command in flutter sdk because no any directory in project so this command does not work in project

Comment: Are you resseting path while creating new flutter project ? as the path showing correct but might chances of it that you are changing while creating new project from android studio

Comment: You have to set the flutter sdk path in Environment variable as path then you can run it from everywhere : see this link for set the path : https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-and-configure-flutter-sdk-windows-10/

Comment: @Hardik Mehta I set environment variables and also try to change path for new project but did not work

Comment: @Aniketmeghani : Please share those path where you have entered as a screenshot as in Environment variable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @HardikMehta check above images

Answer (score 1):

I have got this error for the first time when I create the flutter project using Android studio.

These steps help me to fix the error;

1.Remove existing flutter folder.

2.go to this link: flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/

3.Install flutter again inside a new folder. (Follow instructions carefully.)

Do not install Flutter in a directory like C:\Program Files\ that requires elevated privileges.

4.Set environment variable again.

5.run flutter doctor
(There will be no errors if you set up everything correctly.)

6.**Create a project inside your project directory. (Create project with new location)**

Done :)